# FHIR Subscription not working in hapi-fhir

Tags: subscription, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm using this [hapi-fhir v4.2.0 server with jpa](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter) and it's working just fine. I have added a few patients and I'm able to GET/POST requests to my hapi-fhir localhost environment.

I'm also able to create a subscription using this URL: http://localhost:8080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/Subscription with this body:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Subscription",
  "criteria": "Patient",
  "reason": "Give me the patient",
  "end": "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "status": "requested",
  "channel": {
    "type": "rest-hook",
    "endpoint": "http://localhost:1337",
    "payload": "application/json"
  }
}
```

Whenever I made a POST or PUT to a `Patient`, the subscription should be triggered and send a POST request to `http://localhost:1337` but nothing happens.

What I have tried:

1. Changing `requested` to `active`
2. Changing criteria from `Patient` to `Patient?name=John`
3. Removing `payload` argument
4. Reading the [documentation](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/subscription.html)
5. Changing to `application/fhir+json`

And still not working :( what I'm missing here guys?

Edit: My backend is a simple nodejs running with `morgan`, so it will log every POST/GET/PUT attempt in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also experienced the same thing. But, I managed to solve it.

We need to turn on the subscription rest webhook at [hapi.properties](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter/blob/v4.2.0/src/main/resources/hapi.properties) file.

```
...
##################################################
# Subscriptions
##################################################

# Enable REST Hook Subscription Channel
subscription.resthook.enabled=true
...
```

If you are now using the latest version, v5.3.0, it is in [application.yaml](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter/blob/v5.3.0/src/main/resources/application.yaml).

```
...
    subscription:
      resthook_enabled: true
...
```

Comment: thanks man, I'm not working with FHIR anymore but this can be helpful to others :)

Comment: @noelvictorino I am using docker run the fhir server in local using following command:
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -e hapi.fhir.subscription.resthook_enabled=true hapiproject/hapi:latest` This should have set resthook_enabled=true but the subscription resource is still not triggering to the endpoint. Could you please let me know how you deployed the fhir server locally?

Comment: @nirojshrestha019 I managed to run it locally using `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 2):

In response to @nirojshrestha019, I managed to run it locally via `docker compose` in version `v.2.0.0-rc.1`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  hapi-fhir:
    image: hapiproject/hapi:v5.2.1
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        x-aws-protocol: http
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    environment:
      profiles.active: r4
      spring.datasource.driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    deploy:
      x-aws-autoscaling:
        min: 1
        max: 10 # required
        cpu: 75
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 4Gb
## Uncomment these lines when working on development environment
#     depends_on:
#       - db
#   db:
#     image: postgres:13.2-alpine
#     env_file:
#       - .env.dev
#     volumes:
#       - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
#     ports:
#       - 5432:5432
# volumes:
#   db:
```

**.env.dev**

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD
POSTGRES_USER=
POSTGRES_DB=
POSTGRES_PORT=
POSTGRES_HOST=
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
HAPI_FHIR_SERVER_ADDRESS=
HAPI_FHIR_TESTER_HOME_SERVER_ADDRESS=
HAPI_FHIR_SUBSCRIPTION_RESTHOOK_ENABLED=
HAPI_FHIR_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN=
```